# OCR small image with Tessnet

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I am trying to OCR following image using tessnet.

[image: To OCR]

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried to Re-scale image or convert this image to bitonal image, but it didn't help.

I am using english language pack with following whitelist
`_ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789.,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");`

and OCR code:

```
 var resultScaled = _ocr.DoOCR(bmpScaled, Rectangle.Empty);
```

Can you please advise what operations I can perform in order to improve quality of image for tessnet ?

Comment: I personally had more success with the Tesseract wrapper provided by CharlesW. I'd give that a try, it works almost the same as Tessnet2 and it's  updated regularly aswell. You can find the wrapper here https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract.

Comment: Along with chaning the image to bitonal and upscaling you might want to inverse it as well, so that the text is black and the background is white.

Comment: thanks guys. I found both answers very helpful. Inversing colors helped a lot as well as using tesseract wrapper recommended by Michel.

Now I am struggling with accuracy, basically at this stage I only need to recognize Currency Pairs <CCY_1/CCY_2>. There are around 300 pairs, so I am thinking of creating dictionary of pairs. I've read about "bazaar", but it doesn;t work for me. I followed instructions from: https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html

and I keep getting: "Could not open file, ./tessdata/eng.user-words."